# Get the different size with original file after zlib decompress & compress

Tags: python, pdf, zlib

I've raw data set from .PDF and tried to decompress and compress them without losing data.

Here are some of my code:

```
# Decompression
decompress_data = zlib.decompress(open('test.raw', 'rb').read())
decompress_file = open('test.raw.temp', 'wb')
decompress_file.write(decompress_data)
decompress_file.close()

# Compression
compress_data = zlib.compress(open('test.raw.temp', 'rb').read())
compress_file = open('test.raw_', 'wb')
compress_file.write(compress_data)
compress_file.close()
```

As you can see I decompressed `test.raw` and get the temp data, and vice versa.

So got the compressed file - `test.raw_` but the problem is that's size is different with original raw data - `test.raw`.

When I changed the level of compress, the decompressed & compressed size was keeping to be different.

Thur hxd Editor I knew original raw file had default compression header - `789C`.

```
CMF |  FLG
0x78 | 0x01 - No Compression/low
0x78 | 0x9C - Default Compression
0x78 | 0xDA - Best Compression
```

Regarding from this, I think the best level of compression is `6`. It returns same header but still got the different size.

Where did I make wrong progress?

Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have a problem. There is no assurance that the result of decompression followed by compression will give you exactly the same thing. The only assurance of lossless compression is that *compression* followed by *decompression* will give you exactly the same thing.

The only way to get what you're expecting is if you use the exact same compression code, the exact same version of that code, and the exact same parameters given to that code, as was done by whoever or whatever did the original compression for the data you extracted from the PDF.

Comment: Adier, I need to take a look about lossless compression in more details.
Especially need the approved technical article or public online content for "no assurance that the result of decompression followed by compression will give the exactly the same thing."

Comment: You already know that, since you mentioned the settable compression level. The fact that compression levels exist mean that that compressor can produce at least two different compressed outputs for the same input. Or _n_ different outputs for _n_ compression levels.

Comment: Adier, as you know there are -1, 0, 1 ~ 9 levels for compression.
All of them gave me different sizes with different header excepting of level 6.
Level 6 gave me the different size but it has same header with original data.
I used possible levels and params for decompression & compression.
So do you think original data was not compressed by zlib.compress ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the PDF was not made with Python code, so it would not have used `zlib.compress`. I have no idea whether it used zlib at all, or what version of what code it used, or what settings was used for the compression. That's the whole point here. You cannot expect to be able reproduce compressed data. Period. If you think you need to, then you are probably thinking wrong. All that matters is that you can _decompress_ compressed data and get exactly what was fed to the compressor. That is all.

Comment: It is possible to get back the original compressed stream after decompressing when using the deflate stream reconstruction library [preflate](https://github.com/deus-libri/preflate) or apply my tool [precomp](https://github.com/schnaader/precomp-cpp) on the PDF file. The twist making this possible is to track all the decisions the original compressor made and store them if they're different to the decisions your compressor would do, which gives a bit overhead ("zlib reconstruction data"). After that, the original compressed stream can be restored bit-to-bit-identical.

Comment: @schnaader Very nice.